# ERROR: Invalid input syntax for type numeric (PSQL)

Tags: postgresql

```
create table car (
    id INT,
    make VARCHAR(50),
    model VARCHAR(50),
    price VARCHAR(50)
);




test1=# insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (1000, 'Porsche', '911', '$92813.83');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "$92813.83"
LINE 1: ...ke, model, price) values (1000, 'Porsche', '911', '$92813.83...
                                                             ^
```

**I am trying to insert data into my car table and I have the price set to VARCHAR(50) and anytime I am trying to insert it, it keeps telling me the error above saying that it is a type numeric when it is set to VARCHAR(50) (yes I have saved the file and restarted my psql server).**

Comment: $ doesn’t look like a number. And I would personally never use a varchar for a price, just a numeric and a currency column (2 columns) to store a price. A varchar is useless for calculating anything or sorting

Comment: By the way, you’re most likely connected to a different database

Comment: If I try numeric I would have to change 1000 rows of dummy data to delete the $ and ''. I just want the data in there so I can still see the $ and full price

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, you are trying to insert a string  with "$" into a `numeric` field and that is not going to work. So either: 1) Your `car` table have `price numeric` or 2) You are inserting into a different `car` table in either different schema or database. FYI, you can convert `'$92813.83` to `numeric` via: `select '$92813.83'::money::numeric; 92813.83`. Which is reversible: `select 92813.83::numeric::money; $92,813.83`. So I would save the prices as numeric and do the formatting on retrieval.

Comment: Is there a trigger or check constraint or anything on the `price` column that attempts to cast the value to a `numeric` as soon as you insert a value? (I would expect a different error message though)